# 'TypeError: Failed to fetch' Error cada vez que ejecuto un método POST desde c#

Tags: c#, api, cliente

Estoy realizando una Aplicación Blazor Wasm con su correspondiente API Backend, cuando realizo un GET hacia la api funciona sin problema, pero cuando realizo un metodo POST siempre me devuelve : 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'  como único error, ya ajuste CORS en el lado del Backend y puedo consumir esa API desde POSTMAN o desde CURL sin problema, pero desde c# siempre devuelve error, hay varias formas de enviar POST desde c# he reemplazado el codigo del post a varias otras opciones y siempre resulta lo mismo.

Este es el codigo del Api Client.

```
 public static async Task<string> ApiClient(Uri uri, bool metodo, List<Variables.Encabezados> Encabezados, List<Variables.Parametros> Parametros, string body = "")
    {
        string resultado = "";

        try
        {
            //Declaracion Objetos
            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage();

            // Parametros ++
            string parametros = "";
            string Init = "?";
            string Separador = "";
            for (int a = 0; a < Parametros.Count; a++)
            {
                parametros += Init + Separador + Parametros[a].item + "=" + Parametros[a].valor;
                Separador = "&";
                Init = "";
            }

            // Uri
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri + parametros);

            // Metodo (True = Get, False = Post) 
            if (metodo) { request.Method = HttpMethod.Get; } else { request.Method = HttpMethod.Post; }

            // Headers ++
            for (int a = 0; a < Encabezados.Count; a++)
            {
                request.Headers.Add(Encabezados[a].item, Encabezados[a].valor);
            }

            //Body
            if (!metodo)
            {
                if (body != null)
                {
                    request.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Metodo POST requiere un cuerpo");
                }
            }

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var StringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            resultado = StringResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            var ppp = err.Message;
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

y este el método que lo invoca :

```
public async Task<List<Models.Companias>?> AutorizarUsuario()
        {
            // Encabezados ++
            List<Variables.Encabezados> Encabezados = new List<Variables.Encabezados>();
            //Encabezados.Add(new Variables.Encabezados { item = "Content-Type", valor = "application/json" });
            Encabezados.Add(new Variables.Encabezados { item = "Accept", valor = "*/*" });

        // Parametros ++
        List<Variables.Parametros> Parametros = new List<Variables.Parametros>();

        // Add Uri recurso
        Uri uri = new Uri($"https://{Variables.servidores.servidor}/api/login");

        //Cuerpo de Solicitud
        Variables.LoginRequest loginRequest = new Variables.LoginRequest();
        loginRequest.Username = usuario;
        loginRequest.Password = pass;
        loginRequest.IDCompania = Convert.ToInt32(Compania);
        var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginRequest);

        var Respuesta = await ComunesController.ApiClient(uri, false, Encabezados, Parametros, body);
        var auxiliares = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.Companias>>(Respuesta);
        return auxiliares;
    }
```

Este es el valor de body = '{"Username":"awdawd","Password":"awdawd","IDCompania":1}'

Algo debo estar haciendo mal, cualquier ayuda se agradece.